# Setting values for a Chosen field with multiple select

Tags: javascript, pug, jquery-chosen

I'm using Chosen.js in a Jade template to display a select box of chosen values but the documented way of setting values doesn't work for me.

Jade Template:

```
 select(name='interests', id='interest-input', multiple=true)
                    each interest in interests
                        option(value=interest._id)!=interest.name
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
        $('#interest-input').on('chosen:ready', function(ev, params){
            var myInterests = !{JSON.stringify(profile.interests)};
            $('#interest-input').val(myInterests);
            $('#interest-input').trigger("chosen:updated");
        });
        $('#interest-input').chosen({
            width: "100%", 
            search_contains: true, 
            no_results_text: 'No results found!', 
            placeholder_text_multiple: 'Search...'});
    });
```

Profile.interests and interests are already set when the Javascript is executed. I also tried looping through the option children op interest-input on chosen:ready to check if the options were present at the time the code was executed and they were.

If I just add static options with the selected attribute set it works fine.

Comment: what is your question? this line looks wrong `var myInterests = !{JSON.stringify(profile.interests)};` You cannot access at runtime to jade syntax or jade variables which are only available at jade's compile time!

Comment: That part works though. If I debug, myInterests gets filled correctly with whatever is in profile.interests. The only thing that isn't working is setting the Chosen component's value property to myInterests.